# Is the term "self-supervision" an oxymoron?

Tags: oxymoron

I was suddenly curious because I had always thought that "supervision" implied there being two separate entities.

For example, when I search the definition of "supervision," I get a few results along similar lines. The one from Wikipedia states:

> *Supervision* is an act or instance of directing, managing, or oversight. The noun derives from the two Latin words *super* (above) and *videre* (see, observe).

So if the definition implies a sense of hierarchy (i.e. "observing from above") wouldn't this mean that you can't technically supervise yourself?

Comment: Would you post a definition of supervision? Knowing what you've researched would help us better answer your question.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit it in.

Comment: Yes, it's probably an oxymoron. But there's a difference between 'contradiction in terms' and 'oxymoron' as usually (and best) defined in that an oxymoron involves paradox (an _apparent_ contradiction). Self-supervision involves the/a 'dual- (or multi-)level personality' model of humanity, where your more responsible, managerial 'self' (I'm trying to avoid terms psychologists would use) is given the task (by your will) of keeping your less disciplined, less organised, fun- and freedom-loving self under control (hopefully not squelching it). So, no problem linguistically speaking.

Comment: It depends on the activity. In English, you can “look after“ yourself, so “supervising” yourself isn’t that much of a stretch.

Comment: If someone asks you to "control yourself," who is doing the controlling? For the "self-help" section of the bookstore, who is the helper? The "self" in both examples is both the subject and the object.

Comment: If you subscribed to the ancient idea of a homunculus living inside us, then perhaps he is the separate part of us that does the supervision. (I love how @EdwinAshworth has carefully avoided "super ego"!) However, if you subscribe to the notion of an executive function that is centered in the prefrontal cortex, then you have a built-in supervisor to supervise your self.

Comment: @Lawrence Fine parallel.

Comment: Mind is composed of several distinct entities that carry out different tasks, and run at different rates. If you've built yourself a monitor entity, you can Indeed use it to supervise other parts of yourself. This comment verges far too close to a rat's nest of pointless philosophizing to stand well as an answer.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger Which is why I didn't present it as an 'answer'. The question is off-topic here, as you ... suggest? Imply? Indicate?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. I've been sucked into far too many boius of navel gazing to want another. If there is a Philosophy stack, I doubt that they'd make to this issue before being snared in man/butterfly vs buterfly/man argument. I'm well aware of the barber of Seville, and It's not worth contesting ground with those who are not.

Comment: A team could conceivably supervise itself through mutual action. Think [two-man rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-man_rule) in the SAC.